# fetching data from http://api.hostip.info/

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Fetch city from this xml document http://api.hostip.info/

so i used html dom parser.

if i used gml:name to get city name i got city name as well as host id string.
how to get only city name from this site?

Comment: load it in html dom and then using xpath call nodeValue to get only name of city

Comment: can u write code for it ? because i don't have that much knowledge.

Comment: this is my code:
$html = file_get_html('http://api.hostip.info/');
foreach($html->find('gml:name') as $element) 
       echo $element;
but here i got city name as well as hotid string

Comment: hey Dark Wish,

if i used countryName instead of gml:name in find() then i got country name, it works fine. 
so i think there is a problem with : only

Comment: sorry for late reply Get help from this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_parsertest)<br> are you pakistani?

Comment: i already had look on that page, but instead of that xml file when i try to add url inside get method its not work..

Comment: anyway using split i remove that hostid string. that is only solution i got.  and ha i m Indian.